# Genocide vs. genticide

Tags: english, terminology, etymology, latin, word-formation

I was interested in understanding the origin and meaning of the word "genocide" and went to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/genocide) where it says that "The proper formation would be genticide."

1. Why would the proper word-formation be genticide and not genocide?
2. Does this type of word-formation have a name in linguistics?

---

<sub>Edit: This question has been *wrongfully* closed as off-topic. This question has absolutely *nothing* to do with "Language-specific grammar and usage". It's about word formation and etymology. For which there are tags. It seems this community is not strong enough to correct the mistake of 5 guys. *This* text can be removed *if and only if* the question is reopened. Until then, enjoy the censorship and drama of Linguistics Beta.</sub>

Comment: Maybe [latin.se] is a good place for this question, because it is about Latin word formation.

Comment: @jknappen or at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @jknappen The question has absolutely nothing to do with "Language-specific grammar and usage"; it's about word-formation. It's 100% linguistics.

Comment: @Mitch You are completely wrong. My question doesn't care about the English language and usage. It's about word-formation (linguistics).

Comment: The why question seems like an etymology question, which should be asked on another site.

Comment: @curiousdannii So, what's the point of the etymology tag?

Comment: @jknappen So, according to your logic, the word hydrogen is not an English word. So, questions regarding the word-formation of hydrogen also belong in Latin Language, right?

Comment: @q-l-p You might like to visit and perhaps contribute to [this Meta discussion](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1838/2555).

Comment: @curiousdannii STOP editing my question! You already voted to close my question on false pretenses. My question predates your precious Meta discussion by 8 months. What are you guys doing here? Making up rules as you go along and then apply them retroactively?

Comment: @q-l-p That is only the most recent Meta discussion of many. We have been closing etymology questions for years. I can't explain how yours fell through the gaps originally. In any case, ranting about censorship won't help. Go make your case on Meta if you think this should be reopened.

Comment: @curiousdannii So... you've been closing etymology questions for years. And at the same time, THERE IS AN ETYMOLOGY TAG! Great! Because logic! Makes perfect sense! I'm out of here!

Comment: @q-l-p If you'd bothered reading anything on Meta you'd see that some etymology questions are fine, when they involve systematic issues, language change, widespread borrowings, or are more grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

Because the stem of the Latin word it is formed from is *genti-* (nominative *gens*, genitive *gentis*). So its combining form in Latin would be *genti-*.

The *geno-* form appears to have been formed by analogy with many other Latin and Greek compounds where the elements are joined by *-o-*; but not obviously from other *-cide* words, which are nearly all in *-icide*: *suicide*, *patricide*, *fratricide*, *regicide*, *insecticide*, *fungicide*.

**Edit**: the OED says that this is from Greek γένος, as some of the comments have said. It remains the only word I've been able to think of in *-ocide*.

Comment: So, the error arises from taking the Greek "genos" instead of the Latin "genti"?

Comment: No. @q-l-p. The Greek γένος is not an o-stem masculine like γόνος, but a third declension neuter, and its stem is γένε-. (compare Latin _genus_ whose stem is _gener-_). So I think a word regularly formed from the Greek root would start _gene-_. I think the error arises from somebody who didn't know, or didn't care about, the relevant bit of Latin grammar, but just went by analogy. Like _octopi_ and _stati_.

Comment: Sorry, Colin, but that's wrong: see http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D3%3Achapter%3D24%3Asection%3D59%3Asubsection%3D59, section 873. There are third declension stems that keep their vowel in compounding in Greek: -i-, -y-, -au-, -ou-. -e- is not in that list: the regular formation for such nouns is still -o-. That's why third declension _kle-e-os_ > _kleos_ form compounds starting with _kleo-_ — as in Cleopatra.

Comment: So, @q-i-p, yes, the error arises from taking the Greek "genos" instead of the Latin "genti".

Comment: I do not want to vote down the answer, rather to improve it. Currently it gives the wrong impression. As already stated, taking Greek γένος would correcty give geno-. The real question then arises why choosing γένος over genti- would be wrong?

Comment: Could it be that when you combine words to create a new word, the proper way to do it is to use words from the same language? So, either only words from Latin or only words from Greek.

Comment: @q-l-p Some people think that, when you create a new word from other languages, all the pieces must come from the same source language. Other people don't mind since they're all foreign anyway. See [Hybrid Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word). Personally, I don't think there's right or wrong here, if you know the Greek root, you probably know the Latin and so being consistent isn't like helping anybody out. You're making up a word, anything goes really.

Comment: In collaboration of this: Latin and Greek would not form hybrid words, because the stems are not all foreign to them. in fact, right up until modern Greek gave up, 20 years ago, it would routinely purify such hybrids when it borrowed them; so genocide is _genoktonia_. Classicists would have a similarly purist attitude: hence the complaint about an improper formation.

Comment: Another word ending *-ocide*: **nematocide**, doublet of *nematicide* (nemati- +‎ -cide) under the influence of *nematode*.

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/did-the-romans-ever-combine-greek-and-latin-morphemes?rq=1